# Which is better in OCaml pattern matching, `when` or `if-then-else`?

Tags: performance, if-statement, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

Let's say we have a type called d:

```ml
type d = D of int * int
```

And we want to do some pattern matching over it, is it better to do it this way:

```ml
let dcmp = function 
  | D (x, y) when x > y -> 1 
  | D (x, y) when x < y -> -1
  | _ -> 0
```

or

```ml
let dcmp = function 
  | D (x, y) -> 
    if x > y then 1 else if x < y then -1 else 0
```

Just in general is better to match patterns with many "when" cases or to match one pattern and the put an "if-then-else" in it?

And where can I get more information about such matters, like good practices in OCaml and syntactic sugars and such?

Comment: From a Haskell functional programmer's point of view, multiple when clauses makes things quite easily readable, so I would choose that.

Comment: @vanntile true, I am actually looking more for the eventual effect that using many when clauses might have on compilation/execution time, if there is any effect and if it's any different than using if-statements

Comment: My answer focuses on the style guide, for performance, let's hope a more experienced OCaml'er can help

Comment: Not an answer, but a remark. Your function is equivalent to this one: `let dcmp D(x,y) = compare x y`.

Comment: @ghilesZ thanks but the function is just an example, I'm looking for a general answer on the "when vs if-statement" efficiency question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both approaches have their cons and pros so they should be used accordingly to the context.

The `when` clause is easier to understand than `if` because it has only one branch, so you can digest a branch in a time. It comes with the price that when we analyze a clause in order to understand its path condition we have to analyze all branches before it (and negate them), e.g., compare your variant with the following definition, which is equivalent,

```
  let dcmp = function 
  | D (x, y) when x > y -> 1 
  | D (x, y) when x = y -> 0
  | _ -> -1
```

Of course, the same is true for `if/then/else` construct it is just harder to accidentally rearrange branches (e.g., during refactoring) in the `if/then/else` expression and completely change the logic of the expression.

In addition, the `when` guards may prevent the compiler from performing decision tree optimizations<sup>1</sup> and confuse<sup>2</sup> the refutation mechanism.

Given this, the only advantage to using `when` instead of `if` in this particular example is that `when` syntax looks more appealing as it perfectly lined up and it is easier for the human brain to find where are the conditions and their corresponding values, i.e., it looks more like a truth-table. However, if we will write

```
let dcmp (D (x,y)) = 
  if x = y then 0 else
  if x > y then 1 else -1
```

we can achieve the same level of readability.

To summarize, it is better to use `when` when it is impossible or nearly impossible to express the same code with `if/then/else`. To improve readability it is better to factor your logic into helper functions with readable names. For example, with `dcmp` the best solution is to use neither `if` or `when`, e.g.,

```
let dcmp (D (x,y)) = compare x y
```

---

<sup>1)</sup>In this particular case the compiler will generate the same code for `when` and `if/then/else`. But in more general cases, guards may prevent the matching compiler from generating the efficient code, especially when branches are disjoint. In our case, the compiler just noticed that we're repeating the same branch and coalesced them into a single branch and turned it back into the if/then/else expression, e.g., here is the cmm output of the function with the `when` guards,

```
(if (> x y) 3 (if (< x y) -1 1))
```

which is exactly the same code as generated by the if/then/else version of the `dcmp` function.

<sup>2)</sup> Not to the state where it will not notice a missing branch, of course, but to the state where it will report missing branches less precisely or will ask you to add unnecessary branches.

Comment: I prefer `if x = y then 0 /// else if x > y then 1 /// else -1` (with `///` meta-notation for line breaks). thus having three separate lines for the three alternatives.

Comment: this is also my preferred way of structuring if/then/else expressions, I am just showing that it is possible to chain several if/then/else in a way that looks like a truth table. With that said, I usually try to avoid chaining if/then/else and prefer to factor them into logical predicates, whenever possible. It saves me lot of time and nerves when I read my code later  :)

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the [OCaml Towards Clarity and Grace](https://github.com/lindig/ocaml-style) style guide:

> Code is more often read than written - make the life of the reader easy

and

> Less code is better, cryptic code is worse

The first makes me think that the version with multiple `when` clauses is the better choice, as it makes it easy to predict or evaluate the result when reading the code depending on condition. The second goes further, against the `if-then-else` because, even if shorter, is cryptic when looking from *afar*.

Also, in the section [Functions](https://github.com/lindig/ocaml-style#functions---pattern-matching), we find out that **"Pattern matching is the preferred way to define functions"**

From a Haskell functional programmer's point of view.